# my addEventListener click function isnt working

Tags: function, svg, click, addeventlistener

Second click function wont run and i am unsure why. The first one runs fine and does what it should but the second should allow the user to click on the circle that appears and have an info box show up, but nothing will click im assuming to make said info box appear! I did not add all the html ass there is a lot of paths. Im confused as to why the first one woukd work fne but the second doesnt.

```
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>POLLENATORS PRESENTATION INFOGRAPHIC APP</title>

    <!-- main css -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- load jquery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>




</head>


<body>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1367 769">

        <title>pollen</title>

        <!-- BACKGROUND -->
        <g id="background">
</g>


        <!-- CLOUDS -->
        <g id="clouds">
</g>

        <!-- FLOWER ANIMATION AND CLICK -->
        <g id="flower">
</g>


        <!-- FLOWER PETAL INFO -->

         <g id="flowerPetal">
</g>


        <!-- FLOWER PETAL INFO BUTTON -->

    <g id="petalBut">
 </g>


        <!-- FLOWER LEAVES INFO -->

    <g id="flowerLeaves">
</g>


        <!-- FLOWER LEAVES INFO BUTTON -->

    <g id="leafBut">
</g>


        <!-- FLOWER FRUIT INFO -->

    <g id="flowerFruit">
</g>


        <!-- FLOWER FRUIT INFO BUTTON -->

    <g id="fruitBut">
</g>


        <!-- FLOWER STEM INFO -->

    <g id="flowerStem">
</g>


        <!-- FLOWER STEM INFO BUTTON -->
    <g id="stemBut">
</g>

        <!-- FLOWER SEEDS INFO -->
    <g id="flowerSeeds">
</g>


        <!-- FLOWR SEED INFO BUTTON -->

    <g id="seedBut">
</g>


        <!-- FLOWER ROOTS INFO -->

    <g id="flowerRoots">
</g>


        <!-- FLOWER ROOTS INFO BUTTON -->

    <g id="rootBut">
</g>


        <!-- BEE ANIMATION -->
        <g id="bee">
</g>


        <!-- BAT ANIMATION -->

        <g id="bat">
</g>


        <!-- BUTTERFLY ANIMATION -->

        <g id="butterfly">
</g>


        <!-- TEXT SPEECH -->

        <g id="textSpeech">
</g>


        <!-- SPIDER ANIMATION AND CLICK -->

        <g id="spider">
</g>


        <!-- MAIN FLOWER INFO -->

        <g id="flowerInfo">
</g>


        <!-- SNAIL ANIMATION -->
        <g id="snail">
</g>

        <!-- CLICK FLOWER INSTRUCTIONS -->
        <g id="clickFlower">
</g>


        <!-- TEXT SPEECH 1 -->

        <g id="textSpeech1">
</g>


        <!-- TEXT SPEECH 2 -->
        <g id="textSpeech2">
 </g>



        <!-- TEXT SPEECH 3 -->

        <g id="textSpeech3">
            </g>


        <!-- TEXT SPEECH 4 -->
        <g id="textSpeech4">
            </g>


        <!-- TEXT SPEECH 5 -->
        <g id="textSpeech5">
</g>


        <!-- TEXT SPEECH 6 -->
        <g id="textSpeech6">
</g>

        <!-- TEXT SPEECH 7 -->
        <g id="textSpeech7">
</g>

    </svg>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
window.onload = function () 
{
    "use strict"



    var myBee = document.getElementById('bee');

    var myBat = document.getElementById('bat');

    var mySpider = document.getElementById('spider');

    var myFlower = document.getElementById('flower');

    var flowerPetal = document.getElementById('flowerPetal');

    var petalButton = document.getElementById('petalBut');

    var flowerLeaves = document.getElementById('flowerLeaves');

    var leafButton = document.getElementById('leafBut');

    var flowerFruit = document.getElementById('flowerFruit');

    var fruitBut = document.getElementById('fruitBut');


    var flowerStem = document.getElementById('flowerStem');

    var stemBut = document.getElementById('stemBut');

    var flowerSeeds = document.getElementById('flowerSeeds');

    var seedBut = document.getElementById('seedBut');

    var flowerRoots = document.getElementById('flowerRoots');

    var rootBut = document.getElementById('rootBut');

    var mySnail = document.getElementById('snail');

    var myButter = document.getElementById('butterfly');

    var textSpeech = document.getElementById('textSpeech');

    var textSpeech1 = document.getElementById('textSpeech1');

    var textSpeech2 = document.getElementById('textSpeech2');

    var textSpeech3 = document.getElementById('textSpeech3');

    var textSpeech4 = document.getElementById('textSpeech4');

    var textSpeech5 = document.getElementById('textSpeech5');

    var textSpeech6 = document.getElementById('textSpeech6');

    var textSpeech7 = document.getElementById('textSpeech7');

    var flowerClick = document.getElementById('clickFlower');

    var flowerInfo = document.getElementById('flowerInfo');






    TweenMax.to(myBee, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });


    TweenMax.to(myFlower, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(flowerPetal, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });


    TweenMax.to(petalButton, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });


    TweenMax.to(flowerLeaves, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });


    TweenMax.to(leafButton, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });


    TweenMax.to(flowerFruit, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(fruitBut, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(flowerStem, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(stemBut, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(flowerSeeds, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(seedBut, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(flowerRoots, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(rootBut, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(myBat, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(myButter, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(textSpeech, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(textSpeech1, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(textSpeech2, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(textSpeech3, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(textSpeech4, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(textSpeech5, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(textSpeech6, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(textSpeech7, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to(flowerClick, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });


    TweenMax.to(mySnail, 0, {
        opacity: 0
    });


    TweenMax.from(mySpider, 4, {
        y: -100
    });

    TweenMax.to(mySpider, 4, {
        y: 0
    });

    TweenMax.from(flowerInfo, 4, {
        y: -100
    });

    TweenMax.to(flowerInfo, 4, {
        y: 0
    });


    mySpider.addEventListener("click", function () {

        TweenMax.to(mySpider, 3, {
            opacity: 0
        });

        TweenMax.to(flowerInfo, 3, {
            opacity: 0
        });

        TweenMax.from(myFlower, 3, {
            y: 800

        });

        TweenMax.to(myFlower, 3, {
            y: -10,
            opacity: 1

        });

        TweenMax.from(mySnail, 3, {
            x: 300,
            opacity: 1,
            delay: 2

        });

        TweenMax.to(mySnail, 3, {
            x: 20,
            opacity: 1,
            delay: 2

        });

        TweenMax.from(flowerClick, 3, {

            opacity: 0,
            delay: 3

        });

        TweenMax.to(flowerClick, 3, {

            opacity: 1,
            delay: 3

        });


        TweenMax.to(petalButton, 3, {

            opacity: 1,
            delay: 3.5,
            x: 75
        });
        TweenMax.to(leafButton, 3, {

            opacity: 1,
            delay: 3.5,
            x: 50
        });

        TweenMax.to(rootBut, 3, {

            opacity: 1,
            delay: 3.5,
            x: 100
        });

        TweenMax.to(fruitBut, 3, {

            opacity: 1,
            delay: 3.5,
            x: 100
        });

        TweenMax.to(seedBut, 3, {

            opacity: 1,
            delay: 3.5,
            x: 30
        });

        TweenMax.to(stemBut, 3, {

            opacity: 1,
            delay: 3.5,
            x: 40
        });


    });

    petalButton.addEventListener("click", function () {

        TweenMax.to(flowerPetal, 3, {
            opacity: 1
        });
    });






};
```

Comment: I think you need a [mcve] here. Remove all unnecessary code and add in the necessary paths. You need to cut things down so we don't have to find the needle in the haystack for you.

Comment: honestly Im so confused I made 3 post on this subject and all ive been getting is to shorten my code, I do that and then im told theres not enough code so I add more code then told its too much. I have no idea how to get any help and hoot make the right mark ups. I need this for school or fail and im freaking out and just need some help